# React and methods within child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to learn React. In my App.jsx, I have setup my routes. And they work. One of my components is a sign in component. When I click the sign in button, I need to fire an even on the App. So, I created a function, and want to pass a parameter to the SignIn component, so that I can call the event from sign in. But I'm unsure how to pass the function to the component using routes.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

    handleLogin() {
        console.log("Ahhhh")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <div>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
                        <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
                        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
                    </div>
                </Router>
                <Footer />

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My sign in page is just:

```
export default class SignIn extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <Navbar />
            <div className="row justify-content-md-center">
                <div className="col-lg-4">
                    <SignInBox  /> 
                </div>
            </div>   
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here I think I can use props to get the method, and then pass it to my Signin Box.

My signin box is the form, and here, I want to pass the username and password back to the App to validate. I need to get it to App, as I want to then update my navbar to hide the login button, and show a Logout button.

```
export default class SignInBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            rememberme: true
        }

        this.handleSignin = this.handleSignin.bind(this);
    }

    handleSignin(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState(
            {
                username: this.refs.username.value,
                password: this.refs.password.value
            }, () => console.log(this.state)
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="form-signin">
                        <control-label for="inputEmail" className="sr-only">Email address</control-label>
                        <input type="email" ref="username" id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autoFocus />
                        <control-label for="inputPassword" className="sr-only">Password</control-label>
                        <input type="password" ref="password" id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                        <div className="checkbox">
                            <control-label>
                                <input type="checkbox" /> Remember me
                            </control-label>
                        </div>
                        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" onClick={this.handleSignin}>Sign in</button>
                        <div className="footer-text"><Link to="/"> Forgotten Password?</Link></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I think it's wrong to have the sign in method in the App, as it should be confined to the Singin page - but how can I then update the navbar? The App.jsx is the parent of all components.

(Working code: https://github.com/CraigInBrisbane/ReactLearning)

How should I handle this.

Comment: If you are just starting out I highly recommend looking into redux which provides a global state that can easily be shared across components: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/docs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `component` use `render`, check the **[DOC](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component)** for difference.

Pass the function like this:

```
<Route 
    path="/signin" 
    render={props => <SignIn validate={this._validate} {...props} />} 
/>
```

And inside `SignIn` component, you can access function by `this.props.validate()`

**Suggestion**: Better approach would be to use `redux/flux` for data management, it will help you to pass and access data of different pages and in various other scenarios also.

Check **[Redux Docs](https://redux.js.org/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a function from the Parent like this:

```
class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.someFn = this.someFn.bind(this);
    }
    function someFn(data){
        ...do something...
    }
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
              <Route path="/example" render={() => {
                    <Child someFn={this.someFn} />;
                }} />
           </div>
        )
     }
}
```

And the child component is as follows:

```
class Child extends Component{
    render(){
       <div onClick={this.props.someFn(this, data)}>

       </div>
    }
}
```